# do more action after I publish a post

Tags: posts, query-posts, publish

I am using `wordpress3.5`, I need to write post information to a file **after** I publish a post successfully.

What I am not know is

1. When I click Publish button, what function wordpress invoke to save the post to mysql table wp_posts. I dive into wordpess's code ,found many many php file include.
2. If I want to do more action, what should I do. For example, I want to write the post information to a file.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of hooks you can use, such as `publish_post` or `save_post`, e.g.:

```
// an example of a post save hook
add_action( 'save_post', 'diligents_post_save_hook' );
function diligents_post_save_hook( $post_id ) {
    //verify post is not a revision
    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        // do things
    }

}
```

`save_post` will fire on publish and update, so be aware it will fire on saving of drafts etc. `publish_post` will run on publish, keep this in mind as it will not fire on update.

Saving data to a file is a step I cannot cover, as it is not a WordPress question, but a standard PHP question. For details on writing, reading, and saving to files, reference PHP.net

Comment: Well you will want to use the $post_id to grab data about the post, and then write it out in a file in the desired format. `$post = get_post( $post_id );` is your friend here

Comment: Also http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php